# How can i change NextJS pages folder

Tags: next.js

Refer to [NextJS document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/src-directory), NextJS read the `/pages` folder as default router. Can I force NextJS to read another folder instead?

For my case, it will be great if i can define the router by merging 2 folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems Next.js officially supports only `./pages` or `./src/pages` directories.

Answer (score 0):

For whole is still have problem with this, i found out a possible approach is handling customized router logic in a `/pages/[...all].js` file